# Setting cookies through Selenium WebDriver is not persisting if I set it on base url and then navigate away to some other URL (in the same domain)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, session-cookies

I am getting the login session through some API. I do the following -

1. Navigate to the `www.example.com`
2. Set cookies through Selenium WebDriver.
3. Navigate the browser to `www.example.com\some-other-path`

And voila, the cookies don't get apply as I get the login page again.

However, If I reload the page after doing #2, and then navigate away, the cookies seems to be applied correctly. Any idea guys what could be the issue?

Here is my code -

```
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().addCookie(c1); //I have the cookie object
//driver.navigate().refresh(); If I uncomment it, works good
driver.navigate().to("http://www.example.com/some-other-url");
```

Comment: Can you please share the code which you are using for setting the cookies

Comment: @work_ishaan ```driver.get("http://www.example.com"); driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().addCookie(c1);
//driver.navigate().refresh();  Commenting it doesnot work  driver.navigate().to("http://www.example.com/some-other-url");```

Comment: Can you try to relogin to the the same page again and check? `driver.navigate().to("http://www.example.com/");`

Comment: @work_ishaan Thanks for the quick comment. Yes, it works. But I need a way where I can save one reload/navigation. I have 1000s of tests and it would cost significant less time I'll be able to save this navigation

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the following post which talks about using the same cookies

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15594/selenium-how-to-access-the-same-session-in-a-new-window

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, the scenario discussed in the post does not relate to my problem statement. I am not closing the browser. So there is no point getting the cookie from Window#1 and setting it to Window#2. In fact, I've only single browser window